# TYPO3 - HTML-Wrapper Element not translateable with flux/fluid/fluidpages

Tags: typo3, flux, fluid

I'm using this approach (http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-dev/2015-June/049838.html) to create a nested HTML-Element.

This ends up in an HTML-Structure like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper-content">content1</div>
  <div class="wrapper-content">content2</div>
</div>
```

Basically, this is working fine.
When I first create the element and put some other elements (a.k.a. content1/content2) in it and then translate it, the whole wrapper element including its content is translated fine.
But when I add more elements to the wrapper, translation fails. The element in the wrapper doesn't seem to be recognized (on first translation, I see the IDs of the elements to be translated in the wizard-window - on the second attempt, there aren't any IDs shown.

I attached a screenshot what the wrapper-element looks like...

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Is this still relevant? If so, What TYPO3 Version are you using?

Comment: (I would recommend to use gridelements for nested elements)

Comment: Yes, this is still relevant. Apparently - according to the developer - the issue is not easy to solve, due to some underlying programming of the T3 core. I don't really wanna mix fluid_content and grid-elements, but I'll give it a try... Thanks!

Comment: if you have not already, you should also give ext:mask a try, in comination with gridelements it lets achieve almost any nested content combination. Way better then DCE, and migfht better solve your translation issues.